# Navigation Menu CSS loads slowly, causes it to align vertically for a few seconds?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a regular Navigation menu in my site.master file of my ASP.NET project. I keep my application in server, however time to time when I start the application, or do a postback, my navigation menu like it is aligned vertically for a few seconds and when page loads completely, it is again horizontal.

How can I solve that issue ?

Not necessary but below are my codes (css & navigation menu):

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

And the menu

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
                    IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Administration" Value="Administration">
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_Admin/AdminPanel.aspx" Text="Admin Panel" />
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_Admin/RoleManager.aspx" Text="Role Manager" Value="RoleManager" />
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About" />
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Just think that you created an new asp.net project, I did not change anything, that is why codes are not necessary. My problem is not related with code but with related to slowness.

Comment: I reproduce the code and the result was good. What used as datasource? A DB, XML?

Comment: Make sure Your Internet connection is fast.

Comment: Most likely `javascript` is still loading and the styling hasn't been applied on that point. Take a look in developer tools and you'll see something like `aria-haspopup="NavigationMenu:submenu:3"` which is added for `javascript` popup. Don't know if it's possible to move asp's `javascript` files to the bottom of the page.

Comment: have you used images for menu-tab in your css file. If yes then once remove all images and then try.

Comment: It would be useful to see the actual HTML output. It seems you have running conditions there. So please post the HTML output into your question.

Comment: Are you using any custom fonts? If, say, you're using a condensed font, it could be loading after your elements themselves are loaded, causing some menu items to shift down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide it immediately and once the whole page is loaded you should show it again. So, add a property `Visible="false"` to the `asp:Menu` element, then add a simple script to the page to show it when the page is fully loaded:

```
<script type='javascript'>
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("NavigationMenuID").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

final snippet:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" Visible="false" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
                    IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Administration" Value="Administration">
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_Admin/AdminPanel.aspx" Text="Admin Panel" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_Admin/RoleManager.aspx" Text="Role Manager" Value="RoleManager" />
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
<script type='javascript'>
        window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementById("NavigationMenuID").style.display = "block";
        }
</script>
```

Comment: When visible = false added, getElementById can not find the item, I tried to use jquery too but it didn't work too

Comment: @HOY: So add `display:none` to `menu` class or add `document.getElementById("NavigationMenuID").style.display = "none"` to the script,And remove `visible=false` simply :)

Answer (score 3):

This is called a FOUC or "Flash of unstyled content". Typically this happens when scripts are called on a web page after the DOM has loaded. If you have a javascript or some sort of script adding classes/IDs to your menu, you will get a FOUC until the classes have been added. To avoid this, either target the menu without using the dynamically generated classes or add the classes manually and overwrite them with your script.

One other thing to note, CSS loads before rendering occurs. So if you see a FOUC, you are either loading the CSS asynchronously or updating your selectors after rendering has began.

Hope this helps!

Comment: -1 The class `menu` has been created already and exists in `Site.css` and this is not `dynamically generated classes` / Once this page was rendered by `ASP.NET` the class assigned manually by ASP.NET so the assumption `add the classes manually` is rejected / No overwrite is needed with standard ASP.NET tags

Answer (score 1):

First thing while loading the page could be :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // First line in the script.
     $('#NavigationMenuClientID').hide();

     //Other page scripts..
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     // check navigation menu styles / scripts are loaded.
     $('#NavigationMenuClientID').show();
     // else use SetTimeout(function(){$('#NavigationMenuClientID').hide();},10);            
 });
```

Comment: -1 Hide the menu after that the document was ready and show it in the same function may not solve this problem / Using `setTimeout` is not a standard solution(Causes wasting the time) / Also you need show it not hide it again(In last line)

Comment: May be depending on the speed of network, this may show the flash. But most of the time this should work. SetTimeout with 10-50 milliseconds will not cause much problem or it will not be the considerable delay.  Corrected the hide() to show().

Comment: The menu must be hide ASAP and immediately be shown in window.onload event(Browser fires this event once whole of page have been loaded)

Answer (score 0):

- put your CSS in the head
- put your JavaScript links just before the end `<body>` tag

Comment: The `CSS` already has been located in `head` not anywhere else / There is no `JavaScript` link in this page as shown