# asp.net CSS highlighting menu and panel at same time.

Tags: css, hover, panel

I have a menu and an hovermenuextender. When im hovering over the menu1, the panel drops down but when i move cursor to the panel the highlight from the menu drops out. So my goal is to keep the menu highlighted with the panel. This video demonstrates exactly what i mean: http://screencast.com/t/Bhfj6mtZkPZp

Code:

- Menu

  ```
   <div id="Menu">
     <a href="Page1.aspx">
       <div class="menu-item" id="menu1" runat="server">
          <span class="menu-text">Page1</span> 
    </div>
  </a>
  ```
- Panel

  ```
  <asp:Panel CssClass="panel" ID="pnPanel" runat="server">
     <div id="panelarea">       
        <a href="Panelmenu1.aspx">
            <div class="panel-item">
                 <span class="panel-text">Panel menu 1</span> 
             </div>
        </a>
   </div>
  ```
- Hovermenuextender

  ```
   <asp:HoverMenuExtender ID="HoverMenuExtender" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnPanel" PopupPosition="Bottom" OffsetX="0" OffsetY="0" PopDelay="50" TargetControlID="menu1"></asp:HoverMenuExtender>
  ```
- CSS

  ```
  .menu-item
  {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 225px;
    height: 55px;
    float: left;
  }

  .menu-item:hover
  {
    background-image: url('img/menu-item.png');
  }

  .panel-item
  {
    width: 225px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #626262;
  }

  .panel-item:hover
  {
    background-color: black;  
  }
  ```

What i have been trying

```
   .menu-item > .panel-item:hover a
   {
     background-image: url('img/menu-item.png');
   }

   .menu-item .panel-item:hover
   {
     background-image: url('img/menu-item.png');
   }
```

I have noticed there are other people with similar problems but none of them have been working for me. I really hope you understand my problem and my code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525314/navigation-menu-css-loads-slowly-causes-it-to-align-vertically-for-a-few-second

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Venu Gopal solution.

I have 2 different ways that is "some what working", well almost.

- 1

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function () {
      $(".menu-item").hover(function () {
       $(this).addClass('menuHighlighted');
      },
     function () {
       $(this).removeClass('menuHighlighted');
     });

    $(".panel-item").hover(function () {
       $(this).addClass('listHighlighted');
       $(this).parents('.menu-item').addClass('menuHighlighted');
   },
    function () {
      $(this).removeClass('listHighlighted');
      $(this).parents('.menu-item').removeClass('menuHighlighted');
   });
   });
  </script>
  ```

In example number 1 the menu link is not highlighted when hovering over the panel.

- 2

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function () {
     $(".menu-item").hover(function () {
       $(this).addClass('menuHighlighted');
   });

   $(".panel-item").hover(function () {
       $(this).addClass('listHighlighted');
       $(this).parents('.menu-item').addClass('menuHighlighted');
   },
   function () {
     $(this).removeClass('listHighlighted');
     $(this).parents('.menu-item').removeClass('menuHighlighted');
   });
  });
  ```

In example 2 everything is working as i want but the menu keeps its highlight even tho the mouse is not over the menu.

The difference between these two is, I removed the code:

```
function () {
 $(this).removeClass('menuHighlighted');
```

from exmaple 1. 
Any suggestions now would help me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any script to open the dropdown when menu-item is hovered the following solution might help

Add a class name to menu-item when it is hovered

```
  $(".menu-item").hover(function(){
      $(this).addClass('menuHighlighted');
  },
  function(){
      $(this).removeClass('menuHighlighted');
  }
 );
```

When list item highlighted

```
  $(".list-item").hover(function(){
      $(this).addClass('listHighlighted');
      $(this).parents('.menu-item').addClass('menuHighlighted');
  },
   function(){
      $(this).removeClass('listHighlighted');
      $(this).parents('.menu-item').removeClass('menuHighlighted');
  });
```

**CSS**

```
.menuHighlighted{
     background-image: url('img/menu-item.png');
 }
.listHighlighted{
    background-color: black;
 }
```

Comment: This worked, but when hovering out the .menu-item changes to the hover image.

Comment: Been trying this out now for some time now. My panel-items (listHighlighted) does not highlight for some reason.

Comment: it'll be helpful if you create a fiddle with your html