# Unordered List loads slowly, causes it to align vertical for 1-2 seconds after which aligns horizontal?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I saw this post [Navigation Menu CSS loads slowly, causes it to align vertically for a few seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525314/navigation-menu-css-loads-slowly-causes-it-to-align-vertically-for-a-few-second)
Tried it but it didn't help.

Using it in asp.net project.
Site.Master code:

```
<head>
    <style>
            .body {
                font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
            }

            .navbar {
                margin-bottom: 0;
                background-color: black;
                z-index: 9999;
                border: 0;
                font-size: 12px !important;
                line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
                letter-spacing: 2px;
                border-radius: 0;
                font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
            }

                .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
                    color: black !important;
                }

            .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
                color: #fff !important;
                background-color: #fbb534 !important;
            }

            .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
                border-color: transparent;
                color: #fff !important;
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body  data-target=".navbar">
    <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-bottom: 0px; clear: none; background-color: white; border-color: white;">
                    <div class="container" style="margin-left: 0px;">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <img src="../../Images/Logo.png" width="130" height="40" style="margin-right: 40px;" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar"  >
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                                <li style="padding-left: inherit"><a id="A1" runat="server" href="~/Admin" title="Admin">ADMIN</a></li>
                                <li style="padding-left: inherit"><a id="A2" runat="server" href="~/Configuration" title="Configuration">CONFIGURATION</a></li>
                                <li style="padding-left: inherit"><a id="A3" runat="server" href="~/Reports" title="Reports">REPORTS</a></li>
                                <li style="padding-left: inherit"><a id="A4" runat="server" href="~/Upload" title="Upload">UPLOAD</a></li>
                                <li style="padding-left: inherit"><a id="A5" runat="server" href="~/Billing" title="Billing">BILLING</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
</body>
```

[image]

after 1-2 seconds:

[image]

**----------------------EDIT STARTS HERE-----------------------**

Note: Bootstrap css were not used, extremely sorry for that.
Plain css and html in site.master page are used.

Ok, So I finally, kind of, found the issue myself.

Trials: Tried all the suggestions provided in the answers, Thank you all for that but they didn't help.

Issue: I created an empty aspx page with no content in it and loaded it with master page. What I see is below:

[image]

On the other hand when the page with some content loads it sets the navbar correctly like this, looks like when the Admin page loads it is empty for 1-2 seconds and when it renders it sets the correct style:

[image]

So what I did is I put below code to make it less ugly :(

```
li{
display: inline;
}
```

which now will show up like :
[image]

Any other suggestions guys ?

Comment: Have you tried to check the timeline of your page. Check what it is waiting on from load to applying the styles. Use Chrome timeline in dev mode. Don't forget to tick Network too.

Comment: Can you also replicate in JSfiddle(or similar)? This usually gets a more definite and faster answer. Will also prevent people from just guessing.

Comment: Let me try to put it in jsfiddle and explain it better. Not sure if it behaves same in fiddle or not, anyways let me put it.

Comment: Hi guys, made some changes in question, please see

Comment: @JaredT I'll check the timeline of page now.

Comment: surprisingly, this issue is happening in chrome for less than a blink.

Comment: @Sak from your edited question. Something else from the code is styling it. sounds like a different downloaded resource. Find it and apply it.
tip: Open dev tools and inspect div ul/li header elements and copy the styles and apply it directly. If it works, move from there and make your code pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing the part where you include Bootstrap, and that is the main point. Your navbar is styled by Bootstrap, so it won't be styled until the Bootstrap's CSS file is loaded.
Put the Bootstrap CSS in the `<head>` part of your page in a `<link>` element.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

This is your code without bootstrap: https://jsfiddle.net/xa2ychxn/ and this is your code with the Bootstrap's CSS file in the `<head>` section: https://jsfiddle.net/edaovwjt/

You are using class names from Bootstrap (navbar navbar-default). As you don't have any CSS code to make the navbar inline, when you finally get the expected result that means that something else gets loaded: that's Bootstrap.

I think you are loading something in the page using Ajax, and the content that is loaded contains bootstrap's CSS. That's why you don't know that you are using it, and why it is loaded some time after the page rendering.

Comment: OP said it gets styled in 1-2 seconds. So everything he needs is loaded. Not a question of if he loaded what or not. Its how fast or whats delaying it I wound think.

Comment: depending on where you put the CSS loading code, the rendering of the page starts before or after the CSS is loaded. I know he already loads bootstrap's CSS file, the question is *where*. And since the head tag is in the provided code and does not contain bootstrap, i assume that he is calling it at the wrong place.

Comment: Ah ok I thought you are implying that he was NOT loading at all, because your answer can also answer a question on why styles are not loading. Yeah OP should create a fiddle(makes people actually post the complete code) or place the whole code to fully show what he is facing, if he can.

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong when you say that bootstrap is not used. The style that is rendered after 1-2 seconds is nowhere to be found in your CSS code, but this layout is what Bootstrap does. This is your code without bootstrap: https://jsfiddle.net/xa2ychxn/ and this is your code with the Bootstrap's CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/edaovwjt/

Comment: @Derek  hmm, I am not using any reference of bootstrap in site.master but yes I have it in installed via nuget package.

Comment: you can easily see that bootstrap's css file is loaded by opening the "network" tab in your browser's dev tools.

Comment: yes, thanks, I can see. I use bootstrap.min.css in Admin page but not on master.

Comment: @Derek Thanks, pls put this as an answer. I will mark it. Its now resolved after adding a bloody reference of bootstrap.min.css in site.master.
Please take my 50 hard earned points...  :'(

Comment: See my edit. I think you are loading it from some ajax-loaded content instead of the header of the page. Why don't you just put the CSS file in the head section ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the styles in a CSS file or in a style tag in the head?

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                .navbar { 
                    margin-bottom: 0px; 
                    clear: none; 
                    background-color: white; 
                    border-color: white; 
                }
                .container { 
                    margin-left: 0px; 
                }
                .navbar-header img { 
                    margin-right: 40px; 
                    width: 130px; 
                    height: 40px; 
                }
                .navbar-left li { 
                    padding-left: inherit; 
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <img src="../../Images/Logo.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar"  >
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                                <li><a id="A1" runat="server" href="~/Admin" title="Admin">ADMIN</a></li>
                                <li><a id="A2" runat="server" href="~/Configuration" title="Configuration">CONFIGURATION</a></li>
                                <li><a id="A3" runat="server" href="~/Reports" title="Reports">REPORTS</a></li>
                                <li><a id="A4" runat="server" href="~/Upload" title="Upload">UPLOAD</a></li>
                                <li><a id="A5" runat="server" href="~/Billing" title="Billing">BILLING</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Alternatively, if you do have a linked CSS sheet, check the styles applied to the classes in your header. Some of the elements are probably rendered according to the CSS styles first, then the inline styles are overriding them as elements are rendered.

Comment: Sorry, to not putting it at first. Yes, they are there in style tags. Edited the Qs

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a longshot but can you try using Minified versions of the bootstrap and jquery.Just give it a try and let me know
Try using these :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from external style sheets.
During the brief period where the `LI` elements are displayed vertically, i guess you're still busy loading CSS from external files.

Does it still happen if you add the following CSS to the `style` element in the `head` of your page?

```
.navbar ul 
{
  list-style:none;
}

.navbar ul li
{
  display:inline-block;
}

.navbar ul li a
{
 /* i have no idea if this is right. it is just an approximation. */
 /* you will have to fiddle with it until it is right. */
  padding:10px 20px; 
}
```

(or see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrBZgL))

Comment: I'll put them in head element and check and let you know if it helps, thanks.